# how to extend elixir phoenixframework html form helper

Tags: html, forms, helper, elixir, phoenix-framework

I tryed to extend Phoenix.HTML.Form module of the [phoenixframework](http://phoenixFramework.org). My intension is to wrap the html form helper text_input to create a text input field for a timex date value to use it with [bootstrap-datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/).

I'm new to elixir but I read about protocols to extend elixir modules. So I tryed:

```
defprotocol Phoenix.HTML.Form.Extension do
  def timex_date_input(form, field, opts \\ [])
end

defimpl Phoenix.HTML.Form.Extension, for: Phoenix.HTML.Form do
  def timex_date_input(%{model: model, params: params}, field, opts \\ []) do
    # my logic goes here
    form = %{model: model, params: params}
    text_input(form, field, opts)
  end
end
```

But, it doesn't work, because: "function text_input/3 undefined". What would be the right solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the `Phoenix.HTML.Form` module to be able to use `text_input` - you will find that this is already imported into your views (and your templates since they are functions in your views) in your web.ex file.

If you wish to add a new form function, you can simply define the function (there is no need for protocols - these are often used as a way to extend libraries - [phoenix_ecto](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto/blob/11126cac0b2648164b8ed27f652c86a950ec263c/lib/phoenix_ecto/html.ex#L2) is a great example of this):

```
defmodule MyApp.FormHelpers
  def timex_date_input(form, field, opts \\ [])   do
    # my logic goes here
    form = %{model: model, params: params}
    Phoenix.HTML.Form.text_input(form, field, opts)
  end
```

Then you can either import this into your view (`import MyApp.FormHelpers`), or use the full function name in your template:

```
<%= timex_date_input(f, :date, ...) %>
```